# Statically link a haskell program that uses C++ wrapper library

Tags: haskell, static-linking

I am trying to make a program that, via some of the third party modules, is dependant upon [`icu`](http://www.icu-project.org) library. I suspect that the dependency is via `Network.HTTP.Conduit` but maybe via something else. Dynamically linked binary is not portable even between adjacent versions of the same distribution because libicu* are of different versions that are not compatible.

So I am trying to build the program statically:

```
$ ghc --make -static -optc-static -optl-static my-prog.hs -optl-pthread
```

and I am getting a lot of errors of this kind:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.a(dictionarydata.ao):(.data.rel.ro._ZTIN6icu_5222BytesDictionaryMatcherE[_ZTIN6icu_5222BytesDictionaryMatcherE]+0x0): undefined reference to `vtable for __cxxabiv1::__si_class_type_info'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.a(dictionarydata.ao):(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN6icu_5217DictionaryMatcherE[_ZTVN6icu_5217DictionaryMatcherE]+0x28): undefined reference to `__cxa_pure_virtual'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I believe that I have static versions of all involved libraries (`libicu`, `libstdc++`). It seems as if the linker has not been supplied with `libstdc++` (or is it `libitl`? Apparently the offending functions are defined in the latter).

I tried adding the options `-optl-static-libstdc++`, `-optl-lstdc++` and `-optl-litm` to the end of the command line to no avail.

What is the procedure to statically link a haskell program that is indirectly dependent on C++ support functions? I am running

```
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 7.6.3
gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.8.1-10ubuntu9) 4.8.1
```

or

```
gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2
```

**Edit:**
I narrowed the problem to the package `Data.Text.ICU`, and here is a short program that cannot be built into a static executable:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
module Main where
import Data.Text.ICU
main = print $ toUpper Current "Hello!"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem boils down to the fact that `gcc` doesn't actually have libstdc++, or the other core c++ libraries available to it, but `g++` does.

Asking `ghc` to use `g++` instead of `gcc` for linking should do the trick. Add the following to your cabal file as a parameter under ghc-options: `-pgml g++`. It sets the linking program to `g++` which should allow the system linker to find the libraries it needs.

Comment: This does the trick! (It still does not help with `icu` because it has some more undefined references, but I got rid of the `icu` dependency in the meanwhile).