# Using stack with hsc2hs for working with Haskell and C FFI?

Tags: haskell, hsc2hs

I have a `file.hsc` in my stack project that would ordinarily need to be pre-processed via `hsc2hs file.hsc`.

Running `stack build` instead causes the file to be read as a normal haskell file, without preprocessing.

**Question:** Is there a way to use stack and `hsc2hs` concurrently? Ideally, one would just run `stack build` and everyting would just "work".

Comment: Does your setup work with cabal (+sandbox) ? Can you show us your cabal and stack file?

Comment: What version of sack, cabal, ghc do you use? And what os are you working with

Comment: Possibly related https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/1718

Comment: Have you seen [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37572628/statically-link-c-library-with-a-haskell-library/37643200#37643200)? You might be able to workaround by not using hsc2hs.